# ASP.NET MVC Timeout Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method which is retrieving data from an API using HTTPWebRequest / HTTPWebResponse's and saving into the database.

There's a lot of data and the method seems to be timing out after a couple of minutes.

The web request part only takes about 40 seconds so I'm confident it's done by the time the time out occurs.

For the method I have set

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 1800;
```

For the db context I have set

```
(IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 1800;
```

After calling the method and it running for around 2 minutes, the user is redirected to the logon page I am required to re-enter my username and password.
Is the session perhaps timing out while this method is running?

Comment: It takes 2 minutes to present a login page? Why is that?

Comment: To clarify; I'm running the method and it runs for approximately two minutes at which point it re-directs to the logon page. 
The problem isn't with the logon page itself.

Comment: Random thought, but it sounds like the AppPool might be crashing.  Any events in the event log?

Comment: Shared hosting, not sure I can get to it :/ I'll ask though, thanks for the idea.